# how can i style this activity to be show in square style

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a `activity_main.xml` with nested `linear layout` for creating blocks , but i have a little problem with  this xml code :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/xmlToolbarMain"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="#f44336"/>

    <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            tools:context="gridheader.majid.com.bahaltarinha.MainActivity">

            <!-- row  1 -->

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="3dp">

                <!-- Cooking -->
                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="130dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:scaleType="fitXY"
                    android:src="@drawable/cooking_r" />

                <!-- Celebrity -->
                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="130dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
                    android:layout_weight="2"
                    android:scaleType="fitXY"
                    android:src="@drawable/celebrity_r" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <!-- row  2 -->
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="2dp">

                <!-- MakeUp -->
                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="260dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
                    android:layout_weight="2"
                    android:background="#63ae4f"
                    android:scaleType="fitXY"
                    android:src="@drawable/makeup_r" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="260dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:orientation="vertical">


                    <!-- Kids -->

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="130dp"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:scaleType="fitXY"
                        android:src="@drawable/kids_r" />


                    <!-- Fashion -->
                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="130dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:scaleType="fitXY"
                        android:src="@drawable/fashion_r" />

                </LinearLayout>

            </LinearLayout>

            <!-- row  3 -->

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="2dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <!-- LifeStyle  -->
                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="130dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:scaleType="fitXY"
                    android:src="@drawable/lifestyle_r" />

                <!-- taghzieh  -->
                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="130dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:scaleType="fitXY"
                    android:src="@drawable/nutr_r" />

            </LinearLayout>
            <!-- Fal -->

            <!--<ImageView-->
            <!--android:layout_margin="2dp"-->
            <!--android:layout_width="match_parent"-->
            <!--android:layout_height="130dp"-->
            <!--android:background="#e74c3c"/>-->


            <!-- row  4 -->


        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

This is the screen shot from layout  . Image left is my `activity_main` and image right is  the layout i want to make that . i want to show images in the square style (with the same length and width )not stretch rectangle  :

[image]

OK , i hope you get my purpose and i think this image is be useful :

Comment: Here you can use this library:https://github.com/felipecsl/AsymmetricGridView or just look at their XML

Comment: Another one https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/187

Comment: thank you  Anoop for your result , but i see their code before and , i think nested `linearlayout` is better solution for this work , but now i need show blocks in square style .

Answer (score 1):

Change the scale type of your image views from fit_xy to center_crop

This should fix the distorted images.

Comment: thank you for answer yaw , but i need other solution for this

Answer (score 1):

put the same layout width and height to your images and use centerCrop unstead of fitXY for your the scaleType

Good luck !

Comment: thank you for your answer but , i use the weight attribute for width and i can't set size(in dp or ...) to my width